# Why is React's filesize so big given its small API?

Tags: reactjs

Here are the numbers

- min+gzip 26k
- gzip 90k
- original 450+k

And React doesn't have many features in it's documentation. Why is it so big?

I have a feeling that it's the implementation of lightweight DOM. But I want to be sure.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the source, to see what it does? Helpful tip, don't look at the minified version.

Comment: I decided to ask before diving in code. Though as I am planning to use react I would be diving there anyway;)

Comment: 26k isn't that big at all..

Comment: People are saying react isn't big. Yes, reactjs itself is very small (6.41KB for version 16.1.1) but remember that React requires a ReactDOM to work and ReactDOM has 92.4KB in size

Comment: Though this is not to say React couldn't be smaller if it was carefully pared down. You know, exactly what [Preact has done to give the React API in 3kB](https://preactjs.com/).

Answer (score 190, accepted):

React does quite a bit! The biggest nonobvious part of React is probably the events system -- not only does React implement its own event dispatching and bubbling, it normalizes common events across browsers so that you don't need to worry as much about it. For example, [SelectEventPlugin](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/28eddd16700d5c086c6235b3be9c1674a2fa3a4a/src/eventPlugins/SelectEventPlugin.js) is a built-in event "plugin" which provides an `onSelect` event which behaves the same way in all browsers.

The **virtual DOM** implementation does take a decent amount of code as well; a lot of effort is spent on performance optimization, which is why the unminified version includes **ReactPerf**, which is a tool for measuring rendering performance. In updating the DOM, React also does some convenient things for you like maintaining any input selection and keeping the current scroll position the same.

React also has a few other tricks up its sleeve. One of the coolest is that it fully supports rendering a component to an HTML string even if you don't have a browser environment, so you can send down a page that works even before JS is loaded.

---

What are you comparing React against? `react-15.0.2.min.js` is `43k (gzipped)`, but jQuery is 33k while `ember-2.6.0.prod.js` is `363k (also gzipped)`. Obviously these frameworks don't do exactly the same things but they do have a lot of overlap, so I think the comparison is reasonable.

If you're worried about download size, I wouldn't worry too much about JS code contributing to that. Here's an ad which I see on the right side of my Stack Overflow page right now:

[image]

Its download size is 95k -- I wouldn't think twice about including an image like that in a page because (even if I was worried about performance) there are usually so many other performance-related things to fix that are more lucrative.

---

In short, I don't think React is that big, and what size it does have comes from the many small things it does to help you out. You cite React's small API as a reason that React's code should be small, but a better question might be, "How is React's API able to be so simple given all the things it does for you?"

…but that's a totally separate question. :) Hope I answered your question -- happy to expand if I didn't.

Comment: You totally answered my question. React is awesome. I am thinking of using it for mobile so size is important.
It's just there is not much information around what it does. And I am thinking that there are more tricks I can use:) I feel that I can get rid of jquery stuff. And paulmillr/exoskeleton‎ is just in time:)

Comment: Cool! I think it's totally feasible to avoid jQuery if you're implementing from scratch and don't want to use any jQuery plugins. The only think I've really wanted jQuery for recently is for ajax but there are other libraries that do the same thing.

Comment: I am digging in totally different concept of app building. Check https://vimeo.com/78151404 and https://github.com/component/component - using those you don't nee jQuery at all and compy plays nice with jsxtransformations. And React does hardest job - everything else (Models, routings, server communication) could be covered by microcomponents.

Comment: Note, we are using React on the mobile website of Facebook where size is definitively extremely important :)

Comment: I guess JavaScript file size is directly proportional to the amount of memory that it uses. I think that'll have a larger impact.

Comment: @BenAlpert: Is there any data on what percent of visitors have React cached?

Comment: @lightblade Um... nope. Memory usage depends on how many allocations your code makes. React tries very hard to avoid allocations.

Comment: https://github.com/Matt-Esch/virtual-dom is smaller and faster than React. And yes, file size matters. People love comparing images to js, but they are not the same because images are `onload` while js typically is not.

Comment: I'm curious if anyone knows why React is so big compared to something like [Mithril](http://mithril.js.org/), which appears to have mostly the same set of features. Is most of it just compatibility workarounds for earlier browsers? If so it'd be nice if we had a smaller version for apps that only needs to support modern browsers.

Comment: @Lewis React is supported, maintained and used internally at Facebook, which brings a lot of credibility to the project. It assures users of the library that it is not going away any time soon, and that the library is ready for production environments since Facebook is already using it in some of their apps.
Additionally, take a look at all these big companies already using React: https://github.com/facebook/react/wiki/Sites-Using-React

Comment: I don't know if this is a dated comment, but React is more like ~45 KB gzipped (or ~160KB minified).  

While that's still not HUGE / the end of the world, it's significantly larger than this answer lets on.

Comment: @1nfiniti Okay, updated with some new numbers since it's been two and a half years.

Comment: React also does [pooling](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#event-pooling) of event objects to increase performance, hence the need for a custom implementation besides cross-browser considerations.

Comment: React is not quite big TBH. But when I used it with its brothers and sisters (react-router, redux, material-ui, ...), it ended up with 7MB file size (not yet minimized) even if I optimized my import/export a lot. This is nothing but just my lament :'(

Answer (score -1):

A couple of thoughts.. I had some of the same concerns with it's size, but after using it, no joke, I would use it if it was 5MB in size. It's just that good. That said, I did decide to reduce as many dependencies on other libraries as possible. I was using jquery for two things.. ajax and the automatic ajax response and request handling (beforeSend, etc) that would handle when a token was in a response after login, and then make sure every ajax request added it to the Authorization header before sending. I replaced this with a super small simple bit of native javascript. Works great. Also, I was trying to use _underscore. I've replaced it with lodash, which is smaller and faster, although presently I am not using it so may remove it altogether.

Here is one article, of many on google, that I found that has some alternatives using native JS over jquery.

http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-vs-raw-javascript-1-dom-forms/

Comment: You could also just build a custom version of jQuery with the pieces you use if you're targeting multiple browsers